# Programmatically set custom drawables for radio buttons

Tags: android, radio-button, android-drawable

I'm developing a basic paint application in android and I can't seem to programmatically set custom drawables for my radio buttons. These radio buttons consist of a `LayerDrawable` with a white `ColorDrawable` for the borders and an inset yellow (or whatever color it is) `ColorDrawable` for the center. I put this `LayerDrawable` along with another one (it has black borders to indicate selection) in a `StateListDrawable` to preserve the `RadioButton` functionality.

But when I try `setButtonDrawable(myDrawable)`, the `RadioButton` occupies a very small region even though I specify the width and height to be `30dp`.

And then when I try `setButtonDrawable(null)` and `setBackground(myDrawable)`, my `RadioButton` no longer has its functionality.

Here is my code

```
private void setupColorButtons() {
    int[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE,
                    Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA};
    int childCount = mColorGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        RadioButton colorButton = (RadioButton) mColorGroup.getChildAt(i);
        colorButton.setButtonDrawable(createColorButtonDrawable(colors[i]));
    }
}

private Drawable createColorButtonDrawable(int color) {
    ColorDrawable center = new ColorDrawable(color);
    ColorDrawable selBorder = new ColorDrawable(R.color.black);
    ColorDrawable unselBorder = new ColorDrawable(R.color.white);

    LayerDrawable sel = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {selBorder, center});
    sel.setLayerInset(1, 2, 2, 2, 2);
    LayerDrawable unsel = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {unselBorder, center});
    unsel.setLayerInset(1, 2, 2, 2, 2);

    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_checked}, sel);
    states.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, unsel); 
    return states;
}
```

I've already looked at similar questions, but every solution requires me to create custom xml styles. I'm just wondering if anyone knows how to set a custom `StateListDrawable` programmatically. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
StateListDrawable mState1 = new StateListDrawable();
mState1.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed },
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button3_pressed));
mState1.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused },
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button3_focused));
mState1.addState(new int[] {},
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button3_up));
myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(mState1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This adds to Leo answer. If you want give a state that is false, for example, a disabled button, there is no state - android.R.attr.state_disabled, so you can make the resource reference negative (add "-" before):

state.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked,**-android.R.attr.state_enabled**},...);