# Writing android:button programmatically

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I would like to use the `RadioButton`'s property - `android:button="@drawable/abc"` - programmatically.
How do I write this in Java?

Comment: what's wrong with `setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.abc)`?

Comment: do you want to set the background?

Comment: @java-love no, I want to set the litle button near the option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());
```

and perhaps also have a look at this question:

[programmatically set custom drawables for radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776860/programmatically-set-custom-drawables-for-radio-buttons)